# Error al tratar de instalar channels

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller

Buenas estoy tratando de instalar la librería channels de python pero cuando lo hago me da este error alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo

```
       creating build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\chain.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\not-a-certificate -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing1.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2-duplicate.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\python\test\_deprecatetests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\python\test
    copying src\twisted\trial\test\_assertiontests.py.3only -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\trial\test
    copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win32-3.9\twisted\words\xish
    running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\users\ferna\documents\cursos\django\cropimages\amb\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ferna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z0wazzwq\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ferna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z0wazzwq\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wycrl91z\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\users\ferna\documents\cursos\django\cropimages\amb\include\site\python3.9\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues como te dice en esta linea de error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Debes de instalar **Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0** para que pueda funcionar y debes de ir a esta página para descargarlo e instalarlo.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: ya lo he intentado pero igual me sigue dando error